# MS Access - Appending two queries removes rich text fields

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am appending two different queries with same fields using union. It is working but by doing so, I loose the Rich Text field format to a Plain Text field with tags.

Is there a way to preserve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Rich Text* is just a field property, and can be set in design view. However, when writing a query using SQL view, you can't set these properties, and you can't display a union query in design view.

You can, however, display a query that's using a union query as a subquery in design view.

The solution is to first move your query to a subquery, e.g.

```
SELECT Field1, Field2
FROM (
SELECT Field1, Field2
FROM SomeTable
UNION ALL
SELECT Field1, Field2
FROM SomeOtherTable) As A
```

Then, you can open up design view, click the field, open the property sheet (<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>), and set the text format property for your rich text field to rich text:

[image]